# Upload image on AWS S3 through API Gateway hosted on ElasticBeansStalk

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-api-gateway

I have deployed a REST API on elasticbeanstalk, which uploads the image on s3 bucket.

REST API is written in node.js and front end is in Reactjs.

When I called the REST API hosted on elasticbeanstalk, which can upload the file on s3. After uploading, the file is accessible and displayed correctly.

I have also deployed the REST API on my local host, and upload the file. It is working fine. The uploaded file is displayed correctly.

Alternatively, I have configured API gateway with elasticbeanstalk too.
When I called the same REST API via API gateway and which can upload the file on s3. After the uploading, the file is available on the bucket but somehow that file is not opened correctly. The file seems corrupt. It may be an issue with the access policy.

I also see this issue on the file on one occasion

```
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>10292CE4C4D62A301</RequestId>
<HostId>XJjQBB3DwB6H0lVkS5cHpj3D9ysTa9tApFaacsklg6MGFEnRwyRWLgnVojM8jY3TpCZ6/NQfMogg=</HostId>
</Error>
```

This is the file which is displayed correctly. It is uploaded by calling the REST API directly from local host or elastic beanstalk.
https://images-for-naradej.s3.amazonaws.com/2021-01-14T23%3A39%3A49.938Z-largebanner.jpg

this is the file which is not displayed. It is uploaded by calling the API Gateway connected to Elastic beanstalk.
https://images-for-naradej.s3.amazonaws.com/2021-01-14T23%3A46%3A23.030Z-largebanner.jpg

I am not sure why the file is corrupted or access denied when I upload it via API gateway.

Can somebody help me with that?

Comment: Have you enabled [binary support](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-payload-encodings-configure-with-console.html) in your api gateway?

Comment: This issue is fixed by enabling Binary Media Types in API Gateway. The type should be "multipart/form-data"

Answer (score 1):

This issue is fixed by adding the binary media types in api gateway. The type should be "multipart/form-data"

[image: add binary media types]